# PHP Escaping special characters in a string inside an array

Tags: php

I'm trying to load all my preg_replace requirements into an array. They're a bit complicated, since they're all regular expressions and XML tags.

This is the way the plain preg_replace is:

`$content = preg_replace('/\<MESSAGE(.*?)>/im','<MESSAGE>',$content);`

I'm trying to do:

`$stripData = array(
    '/\<MESSAGE(.*?)>/im','<MESSAGE>',
)`

But when I do print_r($stripData), I get `Array ( [/\/im] => )`

What's happening here? Certain parts are not included in the array string at all.

I was expecting to get print_r as `Array ( [/\<MESSAGE(.*?)>/im] => <MESSAGE>)`

Comment: can't produce: https://3v4l.org/83vbA

Comment: I might be wrong, but I think your printing that on the browser, and as such the browser is parsing the `<MESSAGE(.*?)>` as an html tag. Try this: `echo '<pre>' . print_r($stripData, 1) . '</pre>';`

Comment: Yes it could be, that also returns the same: here:https://3v4l.org/A0taQ

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're reporting is related with the browser parsing the `<MESSAGE(.*?)>` as an HTML tag. My comment is correct about specifying the problem, but the using of `<pre>` tag is wrong as it won't solve the problem. The solution is encoding the array string using [htmlentities](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) method like this:

```
echo htmlentities(print_r($stripData, 1));
```

This will produce the following result:

```
Array
(
    [0] =&gt; /\&lt;MESSAGE(.*?)&gt;/im
    [1] =&gt; &lt;MESSAGE&gt;
)
```

Which will be visible on the browser like this:

```
Array ( [0] => /\<MESSAGE(.*?)>/im [1] => <MESSAGE> )
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply by using htmlentities function:

```
htmlentities(print_r($stripData, true));
```